# Is there a Gradle quickstart archetype?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I used Maven and notably the Maven archetypes.

Maven quickstart archetype (http://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/)

```
project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- App.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- AppTest.java
```

**I want to do the same but with Gradle. Is there a Gradle quickstart archetype with a notice or a tutorial?**

Comment: A basic Gradle Java project is exactly the same code structure, plus an incantation of the [Gradle wrapper command](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:wrapper_generation) to set up the actual Gradle parts.

Comment: Gradle quickstart archetype is a sample but I'm looking for how to make a custom Gradle archetype and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html

But if you want to do custom, I am not sure if it is possible. But with gradle you are able to init project with test frameworks etc.

> The “java-application” build init type is not inferable. It must be
>   explicitly specified.
>
> It has the following features:
>
> Uses the “application” plugin to produce a command-line application
>   implemented using Java Uses the “jcenter” dependency repository Uses
>   JUnit for testing Has directories in the conventional locations for
>   source code Contains a sample class and unit test, if there are no
>   existing source or test files Alternative test framework can be
>   specified by supplying a --test-framework argument value. To use a
>   different test framework, execute one of the following commands:
>
> gradle init --type java-application --test-framework spock: Uses Spock
>   for testing instead of JUnit gradle init --type java-application
>   --test-framework testng: Uses TestNG for testing instead of JUnit

I hope I understand to your question and this is what you are looking for. This feature is still under dev.

**EDIT**

I found this ticket https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1289 and in comments is mentioned that there is NOT possible to init project from template, but there is a plan to support it in future.